# How can I see image of the digits prediction array in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using sklearn built-in dataset digits and running the code in Jupyter Notenook.

I am following this link for step by step guide -> https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html#machine-learning-the-problem-setting

I am currently running the prediction line after training the model:

```
clf.predict(digits.data[-1:])
```

Here, clf is my model.
The output I got was

```
array([8])
```

But I would like to see the image of the digit that was predicted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rehsape the image first as your working with an vectorized array that is 64 in shape. After that use imshow.

The shape should be (8,8).

Code example and output below:

```
from sklearn import datasets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm
digits = datasets.load_digits()

# Predict
clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100.)
clf.fit(digits.data[:-1], digits.target[:-1])
image = clf.predict(digits.data[-1:])

# Show image
image = digits.data[-1:].reshape(8,8)
plt.imshow(image)
```

[image: Picture of 8]

Comment: Please do not use both inverse quotes *and* indentation for code formatting - choose and use only one (edited).

Comment: Can we not have a good pixel ratio